# Is there a way to have leanback's (hidden) Playback Controls to show up in mobile?

Tags: android, playback, android-tv, leanback

I've developed a simple "video catalog" android TV app using the leanback sample from Android Studio. The app works fine in both TV and mobile, with TV working obviously better since I know the leanback features are intended to be for TV apps. The app works fine with mobile phones, and there's almost no difference in using it on TV or phone. In fact, the one big difference and issue I see is that when the Playback controls are hidden there's no way to make them show up again in phone, whilst in TV it's as easy as just clicking a button of the remote.

My question is if there's some way to fix that, to get the controls to show up again after being hidden (in phone). Thanks